# SQL Joining Error "Ambiguity"

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to add a column to a table with "**JOIN**" Command. But I keep getting an ambiguity error:

> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

```
SELECT ORDER_NUM, CUSTOMER_NUM, ORDER_DATE+20 AS PROMOTION_DATE, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME
FROM ORDERS, CUSTOMER
WHERE ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUM = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME;
```

Comment: Do both your tables contain one or more of the columns in the select list?

Comment: It seems strange to join CUSTOMER_NUM to CUSTOMER_NAME.

Comment: I figured it out!.....Thanks for your help people!

Answer (score 2):

If 2 tables have a column with the same name, then you need to tell the DB which one to take. You do this by adding the table name before the column name.

```
SELECT ORDERS.ORDER_NUM,  
       CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NUM,
       ORDERS.ORDER_DATE+20 AS PROMOTION_DATE, 
       CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME
FROM ORDERS
JOIN CUSTOMER ON ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUM = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the select clause you miss the table alias for column `CUSTOMER_NUM`.

```
SELECT ORDER_NUM, ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUM, ORDER_DATE+20 AS PROMOTION_DATE, CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME
FROM ORDERS, CUSTOMER
WHERE ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUM = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems problem of column name ambiguity. If two table have same column name, just write columns as  `[tablename].[columnname]`. In your case `ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUM` if `Customer_NUM` is column of `Orders` table.

So it should be like this:

```
SELECT ORDERS.ORDER_NUM, ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUM,ORDERS.ORDER_DATE+20 AS PROMOTION_DATE,CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME
FROM ORDERS
Inner JOIN CUSTOMER
ON ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUM = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NAME
```